# Prove that $(\cos A + \sin A)(\cos 2A + \sin 2A) = \cos A + \sin 3A$

Tags: trigonometry

> Prove that 
>   $$(\cos A + \sin A)(\cos 2A + \sin 2A) = \cos A + \sin 3A$$

I've tried using double angle and addition formulae but my calculations get more complex. Have tried starting with LHS as well as RHS to no avail. How would you approach working this out?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up the sum-to-product identities - they should help you reduce the left side to the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use following facts:
$$
\cos A \sin 2A + \sin A \cos 2A = \sin (A+2A) = \sin 3A
$$
$$
\cos A \cos 2A + \sin A \sin 2A = \cos (2A-A) = \cos A
$$

Comment: For some reason it didn't occur to me to think of it in that way.. I was trying to multiply the LHS and see if I could simplify to the RHS! Thanks